# Mobile network APN: security implications of "Authentication type" equal "None"

Tags: android, mobile

My mobile network provider instructs me to set up my [APN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_Point_Name) by resetting everything to default, and then only changing `APN` to their value. I see that this leaves the setting `Authentication type` as `None`.

**Is this secure?**

The other options for `Authentication type` are `PAP` and `CHAP`.

Comment: It just means that they are not authenticating your device for internet access. Your SIM card is still authenticated for network access and the network itself uses encryption. They do keep authentication for their non-public APN like for their own staff and 3rd party technicians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carriers will usually use a unique identifier named the [IMSI](https://imei.org/blog/imsi-number) number to identify you and authenticate you and provide you services.

The APN is then used as a gateway to provide you with internet (assigns you a IP and etc'). Since the carrier can identify you with the IMSI, the APN authentication is not needed.

In some cases, a carrier will identify you only by APN and thus will need the  credentials.